# invalid syntax points to "return" in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax

I am just exploring the vast language of `python`. I'm heavily relying on the inbuilt error-decetion and googling to debug my programs. I had no luck this time around. Thank you for your time!

I am getting

> "invalid syntax at line 5"

Here is my python-code of a simple `HANGMAN-game`:

```
import random

def __secretword__():
    secret_word = word_list[random.randomint(len(word_list))
    return secret_word #THIS IS LINE 5

def __ask__():
    ans = input("Would you like to play more? (yes/no): ")
    if ans == "yes"
        __secretword__()
    else:
        print(":(")


__secretword__()

word_list = ["nei", "brun", "ja", "smile", "glad", "gal"]
secret_word = secret_word
sw_list = list(secret_word)
guess_lines = ["_"] * len(secret_word)
mistakes = []
lives = 2 * len(secret_word)

print(guess_lines)

user_guess = input("Guess a letter: ")

while(lives != 0)   
    if user_guess in sw_list:
        i = sw_list.index(user_guess)
        del guess_lines[i]
        guess_lines.insert(i, user_guess)
        print(guess_lines)
        print("Lives: ", lives)
        print("Mistakes: ", mistakes)
        if "_" not in guess_lines:
            break
    else:
        mistakes.append(user_guess)
        print(guess_lines)
        lives = lives - 1
        print("Lives: ", lives)
        print(mistakes)

__ask__()
```

Comment: Try defining `word_list` before the function `__secretword__`

Comment: You are missing a closing bracket in `word_list[random.randomint(len(word_list))`. Incidentally, if the error is on line 5, do _not_ post the remaining irrelevant lines.

Comment: BTW, we ask that questions around code have a [mcve] -- the **smallest possible** self-contained code that produces the same problem when someone else invokes it. This is much, much larger than what you need to produce the question you're asking about.

Comment: Whenever you cannot see an error on the line which is indicated in the error message, you should look at the previous line.

Comment: Also, on line 10, when you call the function, the return has nowhere to go. Try assigning it to a variable.

Comment: DYZ  and Cuber - Thanks! I didn´t see that

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your problem is that the line before `return` is missing its closing square bracket `]`. So Python thinks you're still inside the brackets when you get to line 5, and placing `return` inside brackets is a syntax error.

This is a fairly common problem - if you get a syntax error on a line that looks fine, it's often worthwhile to look at the previous line, and see if your line might be being considered part of that.

Comment: There are more small issues... Look around at it.

Comment: Yes, but this is why the code is giving "syntax error at line 5" (with a `return`), which is what the question asked about. Line 10 would be fine (and common) in interactive use, and if anything it constitutes a logical error which could be debugged easily, not a syntax error.

Comment: Yes, I am debugging the whole thing right now. There are many small issues:) Thanks for the heads up ifconfig.